# How to handle milliseconds in GridDB

Tags: griddb

I have recently started using **GridDB** for a project that involves storing time-series data with millisecond precision. However, I am having difficulty figuring out how to correctly handle and store timestamp values with milliseconds in GridDB.

My question is,
Can GridDB handle millisecond precision in timestamps? If so, how should I format my timestamp values to ensure the milliseconds are correctly stored and can be queried later?

In the documentation, it mentions the `TIMESTAMP` type, but it doesn't specify the level of precision or how to ensure that milliseconds are accurately stored and retrieved.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When working with GridDB's TIMESTAMP type, you can use a format that includes fractional seconds to ensure millisecond precision. In SQL, you can represent a timestamp with milliseconds using the following format:

YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.FFFFFF

Here, FFFFFF represents microseconds. If you need millisecond precision, you can round your millisecond value to microseconds and include it in the timestamp.